# vb.net predicate wrapper error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, namespaces, predicates

So I have a some code I've been using for quite a while and it has worked fine. This project is rather large so I'm using a detailed namespace and I can't get it to work.

I've used this a hundred times, but I get this error on this project:

> Method 'Public Shared Function ProductIdMatch(p As
>   BusinessLayer.DataContainer.oProduct, id As Integer) As Boolean' does
>   not have the same signature as delegate 'Delegate Function
>   PredicateWrapperDelegate(Of T, A)(item As
>   BusinessLayer.DataContainer.oProduct, argument As String) As Boolean'.

The only thing different in this project than the others it the levels of namespacing.
Here are the supporting procedures.

Does anyone have an idea what's going on there?
THANKS!!

Comment: it seems pretty obvious that your method sigs are simply not congruous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, i was going to post that, but it wouldn't let me for a day after I posted the question. I'm not sure why it let me do this before, but it was just a type in the signature.